# Wordpress archive list with year, month, days, posts and comment counts

Tags: wordpress, archive

I am willing to achieve a Wordpress archive list that would be like this:

> ## 2013
>
> ### May (2)
>
> 04 - I love Wordpress (3 comments)
>   01 - I really love Wordpress (1 comment)
>
> ### February (1)
>
> 02 - Do I love Wordpress?
>
> ## 2012
>
> ...

From what I read elsewhere I have to create my own query. I am not really what one may call a developer. Here's what I started with:

```
<ul>
<?php
$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '500', /*no limit, how?*/
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    );
query_posts($args);
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>

<li><?php the_time('j'); ?> | <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>  <?php comments_number( '', '(1)', '(%)' ); ?></li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

You can see what it looks like here:
http://www.vie-nomade.com/archives/

I know need to separate everything by month, then by year. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.vie-nomade.com/archives/ not working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to consider performance issues related to query all your published posts.

I got a similar list, but displaying only the number of posts in each month, in total, I got 70 queries to the db, if I change it to display every post I got in that blog, the number goes up to 531 queries. (including other funcionality on the site, of course)

Montly list:
[image: showing how many post per month]

Every post list:
[image: with every published post]

If you decide to go with the monthly list, you can use [wp_get_archives](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives).

[/end of warning]

If don't write that much and only got a few posts, you should look for something like this:

```
<ul class="years">
<?php
$all_posts = get_posts(array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1 // to show all posts
));

// this variable will contain all the posts in a associative array
// with three levels, for every year, month and posts.

$ordered_posts = array();

foreach ($all_posts as $single) {

  $year  = mysql2date('Y', $single->post_date);
  $month = mysql2date('F', $single->post_date);

  // specifies the position of the current post
  $ordered_posts[$year][$month][] = $single;

}

// iterates the years
foreach ($ordered_posts as $year => $months) { ?>
  <li>

    <h3><?php echo $year ?></h3>

    <ul class="months">
    <?php foreach ($months as $month => $posts ) { // iterates the moths ?>
      <li>
        <h3><?php printf("%s (%d)", $month, count($months[$month])) ?></h3>

        <ul class="posts">
          <?php foreach ($posts as $single ) { // iterates the posts ?>

            <li>
              <?php echo mysql2date('j', $single->post_date) ?> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($single->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($single->ID); ?></a>  (<?php echo $single->comment_count ?>)</li>
            </li>

          <?php } // ends foreach $posts ?>
        </ul> <!-- ul.posts -->

      </li>
    <?php } // ends foreach for $months ?>
    </ul> <!-- ul.months -->

  </li> <?php
} // ends foreach for $ordered_posts
?>
</ul><!-- ul.years -->
```

Comment: Thank you chuck, this works beautifully!
I hear you when you talk about queries. There are indeed quite a lot of posts.
I'm thinking that a page per year should maybe help? When there's a query with, let's say, 4 pages. Is the query gonna be 'broken' in 4 or is it still one huge big query no matter what?

Comment: Note to WPML users: I added `suppress_filters=0` to the query, otherwise it displays all the posts in every language.

Comment: You can always rely on ajax for big amounts of data.

Maybe you can display the posts for the latest month and the rest can be requested with ajax, look into [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) it doesn't have to be a plugin, it can be easily implemented in a theme.

Comment: You can achieve the same effect by querying the posts once, and splitting them into years and months using the same posts array using PHP functions.

Comment: Makes also sense to use page cache (e.g. W3 Total Cache)

Comment: Can i show financial year in archives type=year?? posts published from May to April in a year..possible?